# What dose the operator @ mean in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am reading someone's code, where the operator "@" appears (in fact, I am not even sure whether @ is an operator or not).

I searched around, but could not get any clues. I guess it's some advanced usage.

Here is some example code:

```
hidden = self.adj_norm @ tf.sparse_tensor_dense_matmul(hidden, w) + b

hidden = self.adj_norm @ hidden @ w + b

final_output = self.adj_norm @ tf.sparse_tensor_dense_matmul(final_output, w) + b

final_output = self.adj_norm @ final_output @ w + b
```

Can somebody explain or provide some references that I can check for the usage of "@"?

Comment: What does `+` mean. It depends on what it's applied to. In your case looks like `@` is used as dot product.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mostly @ is used as a decorator. In your case however, it seems it is used for matrix multiplication.

In python matrix multiplication, `x @ y` invokes `x.__matmul__(y)` or:

```
x @ y
#equivalent to

dot(x, y)
and

x @= y
#equivalent to

x = dot(x, y)
```

Dot is the matrix multiplication function in Numpy and x and y.

Comment: x@y is not equivalent to np.dot(x, y) dot and matmul are different operations

Comment: is it unique to python 3? I am using python 2.7